# How to use "more likely" and "be able" in parallel sentence

Tags: grammar

Which is correct if I want to say below sentences in brief

> In that case, we are more likely to do sth1, we are more likely to do sth2 and we are more likely to do sth3.
> In that case, we are able to do sth1, we are able to do sth2 and we are able to do sth3.

1. Add "to" before each "do sth"

> In that case, we are more likely to do sth1, to do sth2 and to do sth3.
> In that case, we are able to do sth1, to do sth2 and to do sth3.

2. Add "to" only before the first "do sth"

> In that case, we are more likely to do sth1, do sth2 and do sth3.
> In that case, we are able to do sth1, do sth2 and do sth3.

update:
the 3 "do" means 3 different actions, for example:

> be healthy / have enough energy / get normal social relationships

Comment: What's wrong  with "we are more likely to do 1, 2 and 3"?

Comment: @fev, the 3 'do' may be different, for example: to be healthy, to have enough energy and to get normal social relationships

Comment: Generally, too many to's are not helpful in a sentence.

Comment: "more likely to be healthy, have enough energy, and have normal social relationships"